# Array.push is pushing an empty array instead of the full array that I am passing to it

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm writing a solution for the Climbing Staircase Algorithm.
The prompt is specifically:

'You need to climb a staircase that has n steps, and you decide to get some extra exercise by jumping up the steps. You can cover at most k steps in a single jump. Return all the possible sequences of jumps that you could take to climb the staircase, sorted.'

My code works - I utilized backtracking, and it should all come out in the correct order EXCEPT... whenever I push a solution into my answer array, an empty array is getting pushed instead.  I console logged to see what was getting pushed into my array, and it's a full array with the correct values.  I cannot understand how this is happening.  Here is my code:

```
function climbingStaircase(n, k) {
  const solutions = [];

  const findSolution = (progressArray, k, remaining) => {
      if (remaining === 0) {
          console.log('pA:', progressArray)
          solutions.push(progressArray);
          return;
      } else {
          for (let i = 1; i <= k; i++){
             if (i <= remaining) {
                progressArray.push(i);
                findSolution(progressArray, k, remaining - i);
                progressArray.pop();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  findSolution([], k, n);
  console.log('final solutions', solutions)
}
```

With the inputs n = 4 and k = 2, this is what my console looks like:

```
pA: [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
pA: [ 1, 1, 2 ]
pA: [ 1, 2, 1 ]
pA: [ 2, 1, 1 ]
pA: [ 2, 2 ]
final solutions [ [], [], [], [], [] ]
```

I've tried assigning interim variables to ensure that it's always referencing the correct array.  I've tried including my solutions array as a parameter that I pass in... all of which seemed unnecessary, and still returned the same results.  I know it's something small that is going to make me roll my eyes, but I cannot see it.  Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is using **one** array throughout, and popping all of the entries it pushes into that array. You probably want to save a *copy* of the array when saving to `solutions`:

```
solutions.push(progressArray.slice());
// -------------------------^^^^^^^^
```

Live Example:

```js
function climbingStaircase(n, k) {
  const solutions = [];

  const findSolution = (progressArray, k, remaining) => {
      if (remaining === 0) {
          console.log('pA:', progressArray)
          solutions.push(progressArray.slice());
          return;
      } else {
          for (let i = 1; i <= k; i++){
             if (i <= remaining) {
                progressArray.push(i);
                findSolution(progressArray, k, remaining - i);
                progressArray.pop();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  findSolution([], k, n);
  console.log('final solutions', solutions)
}
climbingStaircase(4, 2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `solutions.push(progressArray);` by `solutions.push(progressArray.slice());`.

You’re passing the `progressArray` into your function, then you’re mutating it. But since that’s always the same reference to `progressArray`, you’re mutating the *same* array. Eventually, `progressArray.pop();` will remove all elements and you end up with five times the same empty array.

`.slice()` creates a copy of your array.

Comment: Thank you. I had a hunch that it was something along those lines. I had even made a 'copy' of the array with another name to push onto, ignoring that arrays are passed by reference, and I needed to literally make a new array that was a copy.